# Aggregation: Perform countBy on multiple $lookup arrays in a single query

Tags: mongodb

Reproduction: https://mongoplayground.net/p/f9BraX4emor

The playground query does the job halfway. It finds the matching documents, but it doesn't aggregate `bounties` and `emotes` with a COUNT BY operation.

My desired result is this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e7d7bf7d86d85088863f4de"),
    "channelId": "23435553",
    "bounties": {
        "user1": 150, // user1 had 2 bounties with 100 + 50 amounts
        "user2": 200, // user2 had 1 bounty with 200 amount
    },
    "emotes": {
        "A": 2, // There were 2 docs with emoteId == A
        "B": 1, // There was 1 doc with emoteId == B
    },
  }
]
```

I actually don't care about the specific data structure of the aggregated result. For ex. I'd be fine if `bounties` and `emotes` were arrays instead of dictionaries. I think the `$unwind` operator can be used here, but I'm just not sure how.

Currently, I'm making way too many queries to fulfill a REST API request.

For ex, my API receives a request to find 10 suggestions for a channel. First, I run 1 query that returns 10 suggestions. Then FOR EACH suggestion, I run 1 query to aggregate `bounties`, and another to aggregate `emotes`. That's 21 queries...... in a single REST API call.. :(. I want to run 1 query, not 21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an object based on the document values, we need to use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) operator.

## Elegant solution

**Explanation**

1. We perform `$map` operator to get `[k:"...", v:"..."]` structure.
2. Also, we need to count how many times `emotes` / `bounties` repeats

---

```
db.suggestions.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "channelId": "23435553"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "emotes",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "suggestionId",
      as: "emotes"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "bounties",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "suggestionId",
      as: "bounties"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      channelId: 1,
      emotes: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$emotes",
            as: "emote",
            in: {
              k: "$$emote.emoteId",
              v: {
                $size: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$emotes",
                    as: "e",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$emote.emoteId",
                        "$$e.emoteId"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      bounties: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$bounties",
            as: "bounty",
            in: {
              k: "$$bounty.userId",
              v: {
                $sum: {
                  $map: {
                    input: {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$bounties",
                        as: "b",
                        cond: {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$bounty.userId",
                            "$$b.userId"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    in: "$$this.bountyAmount"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QE0K7hF_Mjp)

## Classic solution

**Explanation**

1. We need to flatten `emotes` / `bounties` after `$lookup`.
2. We perform `$group` stages to reduce duplicated values
3. We create `[{k:"...", v:"..."}]` structure to convert it into `Object` with `$arrayToObject` operator.

---

```
db.suggestions.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "channelId": "23435553"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "emotes",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "suggestionId",
      as: "emotes"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$emotes",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "emoteId": "$emotes.emoteId"
      },
      channelId: {
        $first: "$channelId"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      channelId: {
        $first: "$channelId"
      },
      emotes: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.emoteId",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "bounties",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "suggestionId",
      as: "bounties"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$bounties",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "userId": "$bounties.userId"
      },
      channelId: {
        $first: "$channelId"
      },
      emotes: {
        $first: "$emotes"
      },
      bountyAmount: {
        $sum: "$bounties.bountyAmount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      channelId: {
        $first: "$channelId"
      },
      emotes: {
        $first: "$emotes"
      },
      bounties: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.userId",
          v: "$bountyAmount"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      channelId: 1,
      emotes: {
        $arrayToObject: "$emotes"
      },
      bounties: {
        $arrayToObject: "$bounties"
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/erQ-rwYsmMK)

Comment: Wow this is pretty complicated. I have an already complex aggregation pipeline, that i'll need to integrate your answer into. I'll take an in depth look tmrw and see if its possible, then accept your answer if so. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @EricGuan check my elegant solution :)

Comment: Interesting. I like your elegant solution much better. Even tho each operation looks really complex, I can easily integrate it into my existing query, since it's just single $project field, rather than multiple pipeline operations. Thanks!